# Calling Java from PL/SQL

Tags: java, plsql

Can any one please help me on this: I want to call one java program from the Pl/SQL, Oracle RDBMS, the below are the settings

Windows 7 machine, Java is installed on 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02

I created one directory to keep the java files. D:\Java, it has one hello.java file in it.

```
public class Hello
{
  public static String world()
  {
    return "Hello world";
  }
}
```

this was compiled fine, and the .class file was generated in the same directory.

Since I have to call this function using PL/SQL, here is the PL/SQL function I've written:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION helloworld RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'Hello.world () return java.lang.String';
```

and this is the PL/SQL procedure:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE hellow
AS
  my_string varchar2(400 char);
begin
  my_string:=helloworld();
  dbms_output.put_line('The value of the string is ' || my_string);
end;
```

both the function and the procedure compiled fine using the SQL/developer.

When I tried running this procedure:

```
set serveroutput on;
execute hellow;
```

the following error is coming:

```
Error starting at line 2 in command: execute hellow Error report: ORA-29540: class Hello does not exist ORA-06512: at "ORACLE_SOURCE.HELLOWORLD", line 1 ORA-06512: at "ORACLE_SOURCE.HELLOW", line 5 ORA-06512: at line 1
29540. 00000 -  "class %s does not exist"  
*Cause:    Java method execution failed to find a class with the indicated name.
*Action:   Correct the name or add the missing Java class.
```

I placed the .class file in the bin folder also, but still the same error is coming.
Can anyone please have a look at this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can also compile and save your java source directly in the database, like stored procedures:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "Hello" AS
public class Hello
{
  public static String world()
  {
    return "Hello world";
  }
};
/

> Java created
```

Calling this function is straightforward and doesn't need additional settings:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION helloworld RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'Hello.world () return java.lang.String';
/

DECLARE
   my_string VARCHAR2(400 CHAR);
BEGIN
   my_string := helloworld();
   dbms_output.put_line('The value of the string is ' || my_string);
END;
/

> The value of the string is Hello world

> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Comment: From which version of oracle database this can be done , anyother constraints ?

Comment: @SanKrish: [The integrated jvm was introduced in Oracle 8i (1999)](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_8i). You need the [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5014.htm#SQLRF01211) privilege to create a java source or a function.

Comment: thanks . i got it right , but couldnt run the function using the 3rd part of your code  :(

Comment: @SanKrish This is a straight copy-paste from sql*plus, it should work as is. What error message exactly do you get?

Comment: i dont get any error messges , rather it outputs `Anonymus block executed`. I am using sql developer to execute

Comment: @SanKrish That means it works as intended. Just use `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` or your client's equivalent command to read/enable the `DBMS_OUTPUT` messages.

Comment: Thank you :) it prints . sorry i am completely new to this. is it possible to add external jars with the java file ?

Comment: @SanKrish It should be possible, you might want to browse the [Database Java Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e10588/toc.htm) if you're going to use this feature.

Comment: Thanks for your response .. will look into it :)

Comment: @VincentMalgrat  dont think so it is weired scenario like uploading .java in DB and calling from SQL ? In which all scenarios do we need to do this ? In the weblayer only we can java,why to load to DB!!

Comment: @Santhosh dont think so it is weired scenario like uploading .java in DB and calling from SQL ? In which all scenarios do we need to do this ? In the weblayer only we can java,why to load to DB!!

Answer (score 3):

Before you can invoke a Java program in the Oracle database you must upload it to the server.   When PL/SQL invokes a Java class' methods it does so in a JVM *running on the Oracle server*, not on your local system, and the source files must be uploaded to the Oracle system, where they get compiled.

Use the `loadjava` tool, as described in [Java Applications on Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chtwo.htm#JJDEV02000)

Comment: Thanks,understood the point, just one small doubt, in my case, the Oracle and JVM were installed on the same machine, but it worked only after uploading the java source code through the SQL developer to the oracle, how are these 2 different?

Comment: The Java code must be stored in the database. When you invoke it, it runs in Oracle's own internal JVM.  Oracle does not have access to Java code on the system outside of its own database environment.

Comment: @JimGarrison where do we upload this files ? i have jar and oracle12c same machine ?

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chthree.htm

Load the class on the server using the loadjava tool. You must specify the user name and password. Run the loadjava tool as follows:

```
loadjava -user scott Hello.class
Password: password
```

Refer the URL for additional info.

Comment: He should not be on 11.1 - jdk 1.7 is not supported there (when need to load .class files)